# Remove Configuration Installer (v1.8)

Tags: 8, configuration

I'm upgrading a site from Drupal 8 to Drupal 9. One of the projects that is deprecated and incompatible with Drupal 9 is [Configuration Installer](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_installer)

The "normal" workflow (e.g., `drush pmu` <module_name> doesn't work - perhaps because this thing isn't really a module?)
I can't simply remove the project with composer because then `drush cim` fails because it expects the code to be in the base.

It is like *Hotel California* "You can check out any time you like
But you can never leave!"

Answer (score 3):

[Configuration installer](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_installer) is an installation profile, not a module. It's like one of the standard installation profiles that comes with Drupal core, such as [Standard](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21profiles%21standard%21standard.info.yml/9.2.x) or [Minimal](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21profiles%21minimal%21minimal.info.yml/9.2.x).

Once the site is installed using an installation profile, you cannot change the used installation profile anymore; it's not like a module that can be uninstalled and replaced with a different module. That's why an installation profile doesn't implement `hook_uninstall()`.

The only way to use a different installation profile for a site is reinstalling Drupal and choose the default installation profile (*Standard*).

Manually changing the installation profile would require to change any reference to the old installation profile in the database with the reference to the new installation profile, execute the new profile `hook_install()` implementation, and eventually reverse the changes done from the old profile `hook_install()` implementation.
There is still the configuration added with the configuration files in the config/install and config/optional directories for the installation profiles. (See for example, [config/install](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/tree/9.2.x/core/profiles/standard/config/install) and [config/optional](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/tree/9.2.x/core/profiles/standard/config/optional) for the *Standard* profile.) The configuration from the old profile should be removed, and the one from the new profile added.

Comment: Thank you for the response. You're right about it not being a module - (that's why referred to it as a project)
Anyway; I think (hope) you're incorrect about the only remedy being a reinstall. 

I got a reply from the maintainer of Configuration Install; referencing https://www.drupal.org/project/profile_switcher - which implies that switching profiles might be the way out of this 

There is also this reference: https://www.messageagency.com/blog/changing-install-profiles-drupal-8

Comment: That blog post only shows the code for setting the installation profile, which doesn't run its `hook_install()`. I am not sure that simply changing the installation profile name makes Drupal invoke any hook on that installation profile. Then, there are still the configuration entities from the old profile and the new one.